# How to set random seed RCPP code?

Tags: r, random, rcpp, armadillo

I have three computers: Two Windows 10 and one Win7.

I'm developing a code using RCPP and RcppArmadillo in Rstudio.

I don't know the problem that's going on, but on my computer from my house the seed when I compile the algorithm, the seed is being fixed. Ex:

First I generate a matrix with uniform function and normalizo it.

```
U. Randu ();

U = Normalise (U, 1, 1, 1);

cout < < Endl;
```

When I compile on computers (WIN7 and WIN10) generates random matrices, but on one of my computers the seed seems to be fixed.

It only works if I put set. `Seed (NULL)`.

Already tried to use `ARMA_RNG:: Set_seed_random ()` and does not work, the following message appears:

Warning message:

> In Algoritmo_IFCMADC (x, K = 4): When called from R, the RNG seed has
>   to be set at the R level via set. Seed ()

What I can't understand is that the same code is being rotated on different computers, and in one of them the seed is fixed.

Comment: Re: the warning, note from @coatless excellent and detailed answer to the question marked as a possible dupe: "you cannot use arma::arma_rng::set_seed() to set the seed due to limitations of the R/C++ interaction detailed in Section 6.3 of Writing R Extensions".

Comment: Re: your main problem, can we get a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? In particular, it might be helpful in this case to see your includes and your entire function. Considering, for example, the use of `cout` rather than `Rcpp::Rcout`, your code may not properly consider R/C++ integration issues, and in particular I wonder if the issue isn't related to not setting the R RNG state via, for example, exporting using attributes.

Comment: It's worked! I used   GetRNGstate() before and PutRNGstate() after the function .randu(). [Random number generation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Random-numbers)

  GetRNGstate();
  U.randu();
  U = normalise(U,1,1);
  cout << U << endl;
  PutRNGstate();

But I can not understand, because on other computer does not need to place functions and works, a seed is not fixed. On my computer, it works only When I put this two functions. Somebody know?